# Tick checkbox simultaneously

Tags: php

```
<?php        
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM medicine");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]"  id="chkbox"class="case" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];  ?>" /></td>
    <td ><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxx[]" id="chkboxx" class="case" value="<?php echo $row['Price'];  ?>"/></td>

<?php
  }
?>
```

I have this 2 column of checkbox and I need to tick both of those at 
simultaneously. Is it posible?

What I mean is if column name is checked then automatically column price is also checked.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Easiest to use javascript for this so it doesnt have to come from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can, but you can put it on array and work with it were you want   :

1. Add database values in page

   ```
   <?php        
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM medicine");
     $array_list=array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $array_list[]=$row;
     }

     $i=0;

     foreach($array_list as $key)
     {
       echo '
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]"  onclick="checkdo(\'chkboxx'.$i.'\')" id="chkbox'.$i.'"class="case" value="'.$row['Name'].'" /></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxx[]" id="chkboxx'.$i.'" class="case" value="'.$row['Price'].'"/></td>
       </tr>';

       $i++;
   }
   ```
2. Javascript process

Let's say that this the output of the first process to tick two check box in same time you can use jQuery - see the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function checkdo(chid)
{
    $('#'+chid).click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]"  id="chkbox"class="case" value="" /></td>
    <td ><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxx[]" id="chkboxx" class="case" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i still dont understand because im not good when its come to array , can i use javascript instead of array ? or can you help me what to do next after the answer that you had given

Comment: javascript i think will not need javascript here because you get the data from db and transfer it into array and add it to html is that what you want right ?

Comment: At first i tried to put two variable on same checkbox , but after i make some research i know its not possible . So i tried this way ,  and i stuck .  i need to tick two checkbox at the same time so that i can hide the 2nd chekcbox . The two checkbox value i want to insert in my db . Can you help me what i need to do after the array?

Comment: its worked on the first row , for the second row and until the end , it didnt ticked simultaneously . Can i contact you somehow so that i can send you the whole code ?

Comment: ah i forget the loop yep try it again i update it i added $i to make diffrent id and a function make the tick

Comment: Thanks bro , its work now , thanks for your help , i really appreciate it .

Comment: You welcome brother , you can just make vote up and mark it as answer, to help other people